# One logic implementation for Web and Console Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, console

I am new in C# console application.

I have a question: I want to create a MVC project using Entity Framework, I have made some logic to import data one table to another.

Now as per client requirement I need to create a console application for same logic.

Now my question is : how can I use my mvc application logic in my console application?

So if I need to do any changes in my code, I have to change only in web applicaion not in console app.

Please suggest a good way to make efficient my logic

Thanks

Comment: You'll end up with 3 projects; the web application, the console application, and **a shared library that contains anything both need to do**.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett you can make the comment as answer :)

Comment: Didn't think it was enough on its own. Fleshed it out into an answer now.

Comment: i  have  create  library  for  both  ..  while  running  my console  application  i  am  getting  error  resource can not found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll end up with 3 projects;

- The Web Application
- The Console Application
- A Shared Library

---

What you would do is,

1. Refactor the shared logic so it exists in separate methods and doesn't depend on any shared state specific to the web application.
2. Test the web application still works.
3. Take out the shared logic and put that in the shared library.
4. Add a reference to the shared library from your web application.
5. Change the web application to call the functions in your shared library from the web application.
6. Test to ensure it still works.
7. Create your console application.
8. Add a reference to your shared library from the console application.
9. Call your functions in the shared library as needed from the console application.
10. Test to ensure it works
11. Yay, you're done! \o/

Comment: can  you provide any  link  for  test  application .. i am not getting  share code concept

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate a bit on George's answer, you need to implement SOC (separation of concerns) in your app. MVC is a framework that helps you do that, there is also MVP which could be even a better solution in your case.